# How to make LibGDX Actions moveTo() animate from one point to another in a curved line?

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, interpolation, scene2d

I am working on a project in LibGDX, and I am using **Scene2D** actors for some of my sprites. In this regard, I have a sprite, which is spawning somewhere on the screen and needs to move to another position on the screen. To do this I am using the `moveTo(xPos, yPos, duration, interpolation)` method in the Actions, to make the move animation.

However, when I use this approach, the actor moves like I told it to, but it only moves in a straight line, from point A to B. I have tried several Interpolation options, like Circle interpolation and such, but it seems only to impact the speed of the animation line.

So now my question: How do I make my animation make a smooth curved line (See picture), from A to B?
[image]

I am currently using this code to make the Actions animation:

```
adultCustomerPointActor.addAction(Actions.sequence(
    Actions.moveTo(300, 200, 2f, Interpolation.circle)
));
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: First you need to decide what curve you want. I guess you want a circular arc, but with what radius, and should it be clockwise or counter-clockwise? After you know this, you can calculate the center point of the circle, and the starting and ending angles that will connect points at A and B. Write a subclass of TemporalAction that implements the motion. You can look at MoveToAction as an template for writing your class. BTW, interpolation is a parameter for the speed of the motion, not the path.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to calculate this? I am not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: have you made it work?

Comment: In some way, but it didn't behave in a smooth circular arc, so I dropped it, and moved forward with some other issues in the game

Answer (score 2):

It's a geometry problem. Using vectors, find the point halfway between the two points:

```
vec1.set(bx, by).sub(ax, ay).scl(0.5f).add(ax, ay);
```

Get another vector that is 90 or 270 to from the vector between the points:

```
vec2.set(bx, by).sub(ax, ay).rotate90().add(vec1);
```

This `vec2` can be scaled to adjust how extreme curvature of the arc is. If you leave it alone, you'll have a quarter circle. You can also scale it negative to reverse the curvature.

Then add the second vector to the first to find the center point of your arc, which we can call point C.

```
vec1.set(bx, by).sub(vec2); // CB
vec3.set(ax, ay).sub(vec2); // CA
float angle = vec1.angle(vec3);
```

Now you need a vector that points from point C to point A. You will rotate this vector until it reaches point B. So you need the angle between CA and CB.

So here's a very simplistic class that implements this. It doesn't account yet for deciding if you want the arc to go up or down and if you want to scale how extreme it looks. You could add those as additional parameters with getters/setters. I haven't tested it, so it may need some debugging.

```
public class ArcToAction extends MoveToAction {
    private float angle;
    private final Vector2 vec1 = new Vector2(), vec2 = new Vector2(), vec3 = new Vector2();

    @Override
    protected void begin () {
        super.begin();
        float ax = target.getX(getAlignment()); // have to recalculate these because private in parent
        float ay = target.getY(getAlignment());
        vec1.set(getX(), getY()).sub(ax, ay);
        vec2.set(vec1).rotate90();
        vec1.scl(0.5f).add(ax, ay);
        vec2.add(vec1);
        vec1.set(bx, by).sub(vec2); // CB
        vec3.set(ax, ay).sub(vec2); // CA
        angle = vec1.angle(vec3);
    }

    protected void update (float percent) {
        if (percent >= 1){
            target.setPosition(getX(), getY(), getAlignment());
            return;
        }

        vec1.set(vec3).rotate(percent * angle);
        target.setPosition(vec1.x, vec1.y, getAlignment());
    }

}
```

If you want to support automatic pooling, you can add a method like this:

```
static public ArcToAction arcTo (float x, float y, float duration, Interpolation interpolation) {
    ArcToAction action = Actions.action(ArcToAction .class);
    action.setPosition(x, y);
    action.setDuration(duration);
    action.setInterpolation(interpolation);
    return action;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this but it doesn't show anything on the screen. I added bx and by which is actor.getX and getY right? For rotate90() I pass in 1.

Comment: Yes I think that’s what bx and by should be. I wrote this four years ago and didn’t test it so I must have neglected that. I don’t know if it has other bugs. You can step through with a debugger and see if the math makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, I came across it while searching for an answer and decided to implement the following class to enable arcing from point A to point B. Feel free to use it in your own projects.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Interpolation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.MoveToAction;

/**
 * This class extends MoveToAction to move an actor along an arc.
 */
public class ArcMovetoAction extends MoveToAction {
  private float height;
  private float length;
  private float angle;
  private float a;
  private float b;
  private final Vector2 position = new Vector2();

  /**
   * Sets the height of the arc.
   *
   * @param height the height of the arc
   */
  private void setHeight(float height) {
    this.height = height;
  }

  /**
   * Called when the action starts.
   */
  @Override
  protected void begin() {
    super.begin();

    float startX = getStartX();
    float startY = getStartY();
    float endX = getX();
    float endY = getY();

    length = (float) Math.hypot(endX - startX, endY - startY);

    a = (float) ((startY - height) / Math.pow(startX - length / 2, 2));
    b = -2 * a * length / 2;

    Vector2 start = new Vector2(startX, startY);
    Vector2 end = new Vector2(endX, endY);

    if (endX < startX) {
      end.x = -end.x;
    }

    angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(end.y - start.y, end.x - start.x));
  }

  /**
   * Updates the action based on the percent done.
   *
   * @param percent the percent done
   */
  @Override
  protected void update(float percent) {
    if (percent == 0 || percent >= 1 || height == 0) {
      super.update(percent);
      return;
    }

    float x = percent * length;
    float y = (float) (a * Math.pow(x, 2) + b * x);

    position.set(x, y).add(getStartX(), getStartY()).rotateDeg(angle);

    if (getX() < getStartX()) {
      position.x = -position.x;
    }

    target.setPosition(position.x, position.y, getAlignment());
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new ArcMovetoAction.
   *
   * @param x             the x-coordinate to move to
   * @param y             the y-coordinate to move to
   * @param height        the height of the arc
   * @param duration      the duration of the action
   * @param interpolation the interpolation to use
   * @return the created ArcMovetoAction
   */
  public static ArcMovetoAction arcTo(float x, float y, float height, float duration, Interpolation interpolation) {
    ArcMovetoAction action = Actions.action(ArcMovetoAction.class);
    action.setPosition(x, y);
    action.setDuration(duration);
    action.setInterpolation(interpolation);
    action.setHeight(height);
    return action;
  }
}
```